# How do I speed up rotating a block of bits?

Tags: haskell, optimization, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm writing a program that does the same thing in Rust and Haskell. It's a whole-message cipher; it reads in an entire file, encrypts it, and writes it out. Given 1 MiB, the Rust code takes 2.4 s, but the Haskell code takes 18.7 s. I profiled it and found that 36.6% of time and allocation is taken by the `rotBitcount` function. This copies one array to another, rotating the whole array by its number of one bits. Here's the code:

```
module Cryptography.WringTwistree.RotBitcount
  ( rotBitcount
  ) where

{- This module is used in both Wring and Twistree.
 - It rotates an array of bytes by a multiple of its bitcount,
 - producing another array of the same size. As long as the multiplier
 - is relatively prime to the number of bits in the array, this
 - operation satisfies the strict avalanche criterion. Changing *two*
 - bits, however, has half a chance of changing only two bits in
 - the output.
 -
 - Bit 0 of byte 0 is bit 0 of the array. Bit 0 of byte 1 is bit 8 of the array.
 - e1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00, rotated by its bitcount (4), becomes
 - 10 0e 00 00 00 00 00 00.
 -}

import Data.Bits
import Data.Word
import Data.Array.Unboxed

rotBitcount :: (Integral a,Ix a,Bits a) => UArray a Word8 -> a -> UArray a Word8
-- The type a may be signed or unsigned, but the array index must begin at 0.
-- a should hold the square of eight times the bounds; so if the bounds are
-- (0..31), Word16 is adequate, but Int16 and Word8 are not.
rotBitcount src mult = array bnd
  [ (i, (src ! ((i+len-byte)   `mod` len) `shift` bit) .|.
        (src ! ((i+len-byte-1) `mod` len) `shift` (bit-8))) | i <- [0..(len-1)]]
  where
    bnd = bounds src
    len = (snd bnd) +1
    multmod = mult `mod` (len * 8)
    bitcount = fromIntegral $ sum $ map popCount $ elems src
    rotcount = (bitcount * multmod) `mod` (len * 8)
    byte = rotcount `shift` (-3)
    bit = fromIntegral (rotcount .&. 7)
```

I'm compiling it with a simple `stack run`, except when profiling. Stack version is 2.11.1. The repo is at https://github.com/phma/wring-twistree . How can I make it faster?

Comment: I suspect Rust can unroll a lot that GHC doesn't. Perhaps it even fuses the 8-bit operations into 64-bit ones, which would obviously be much faster. Incidentally, why don't you use `Word64` right away?

Comment: The message size may be odd, or the machine may be big-endian. Also, other steps in the cipher work on bytes. The next most time-consuming code is `mix3Parts`, but that takes less than half the time `rotBitcount` does.

Comment: I'd strongly consider using the `vector` package, to start with, not `Data.Array.Unboxed`.

Comment: You might like [`ixmap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/GHC-Arr.html#v:ixmap). It's likely to be faster than building lots of tuples/cons cells just for `array` to immediately destruct them.

Comment: `ixmap` wouldn't work. 7/8 of the time, each output byte depends on two input bytes, and `ixmap` can't handle that.

Comment: @PierreAbbat Good point. I suppose you could still try making two new arrays and merging them... though I am significantly less optimistic that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

After talking with some people on IRC, I got it running faster. The steps were:

1. Specialize `rotBitcount` all the way up. The main program uses `UArray Int Word8`, so I added these lines:

```
{-# SPECIALIZE rotBitcount :: UArray Int Word8 -> Int -> UArray Int Word8 #-}
{-# SPECIALIZE roundEncrypt :: Int -> UArray (Word8,Word8) Word8 ->
    UArray Int Word8 -> UArray Int Word8 -> Int -> UArray Int Word8 #-}
{-# SPECIALIZE roundDecrypt :: Int -> UArray (Word8,Word8) Word8 ->
    UArray Int Word8 -> UArray Int Word8 -> Int -> UArray Int Word8 #-}
{-# SPECIALIZE encrypt :: Wring -> UArray Int Word8 -> UArray Int Word8 #-}
{-# SPECIALIZE decrypt :: Wring -> UArray Int Word8 -> UArray Int Word8 #-}
```

In case someone wants to use it with an array indexed by `Word` or `Int64`, I can add more specializations.

2. Add strictness annotations in the `where` clause. The reason is that, if the message length is zero, these numbers would not be computed lazily, so the compiler has to box them.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
...
    !len = (snd bnd) +1
    !byte = rotcount .>>. 3
    !bit = fromIntegral (rotcount .&. 7)
```